# Count the (fraction of) neighbours of a value in a numpy array with the same value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I am trying to count/find the fraction of neighbour of the same value, for each entry in a numpy array. It needs to be performant ( run many times, on larger arrays), possibly with the ability to change the neighborhood definition (rook/queen, ie 4 neighbors: NSEW, vs 8 neighbours: NE,N,NW,E,W,SE,S,SW), and able to set 0 as a NaN or not.

Consider a simple integer numpy array:

```
a = np.zeros((6,6), dtype=np.int64)
a[1,2] = a[1,3] = 1
a[4,4] = a[5,4] = a[5,5] = 3
a[4,3] = 2
```

Which looks like:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 2 3 0]
[0 0 0 0 3 3]]
```

I would like to generate the following array, where we consider 0 masked out ( not a number):

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 2 0]
[0 0 0 0 2 2]]
```

Or better, if expressed as fractions:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1/8 1/8 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 2/8 0]
[0 0 0 0 2/5 2/3]]
```

I have considered similarities with scipy convolutions, except they bring up sums, not counts.

Comment: Sums are counts

Comment: Also, you're missing an element on the second to last row

Comment: Sums are not count ( it may sum up many different elements, I am only interested of those that have the same value, and I may not know the value itself). I do not understand what you mean about a missing element on the second to last line. Ifit is the result for the "2", it is not missing = there are zero elements of the same value as neighbours.

Comment: You're right. I meant that counts are sums. Also, I didn't get the fact that you're counting only similar elements from your question. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

A convolution is exactly what you're looking for. For example, [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html). Consider the following kernel:

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=int)
kernel[1, 1] = 0
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

This is a hollow ring. The kernel will add up the number of surrounding elements at each location. You need to operate on bools for it to work properly though.

Additionally, since you want to count only like elements, you will want to create an array that separates out the unique elements into individual planes. As it happens, you can do that simultaneously with creating a boolean array:

```
u = np.unique(a)  # array([0, 1, 2, 3])
b = a == u[1:, None, None]
```

You can now apply the convolution directly, if you add one more dimension to the kernel:

```
counts = convolve(b, kernel[None, ...], 'same')
```

This will return non-zero at locations other than the original non-zeros, so you have to mask it:

```
counts *= b
```

Finally, you can now sum the non-zero elements of `counts` across the extra label dimension:

```
counts = counts.sum(0)
```

This convolution returns the diagonal elements as well as the immediate neighbors. To return the latter, use this kernel instead:

```
kernel = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)
kernel[0, 1] = kernel[2, 1] = kernel[1, 0] = kernel[1, 2] = 1
# array([[0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0]])
```

The other convolution function in scipy, [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html), is much less suitable here, though you could arguably use it too:

```
counts = convolve(b.view(np.uint8), kernel, mode='constant', cval=0)
```

Notice the argument `b.view(np.uint8)`. You need to do that or equivalent (e.g. `b.astype(int)`) to avoid getting an array of booleans rather than counts.

**TL;DR**

```
from scipy.signal import convolve

kernel = np.ones((1, 3, 3), dtype=int)
kernel[0, 1, 1] = 0
b = a == np.unique(a)[1:].reshape(-1, 1, 1)
counts = (b * convolve(b, kernel, 'same')).sum(0)
```

Comment: I will experiment, but I do not immediately see how this works ( I did experiment exactly as above with the ring kernel). As you say: "The kernel will add up the number of surrounding elements at each location." BUt that is not what I want - it would add a weighted sum ( so a 2*x, or a 3*1 etc, and it would not distinguish the values that are *identical* to the value at the cell investigated. I will try the approach, but maybe I did not explain what I want correctly.

Comment: Note what happens to the value of 2 in my example, at a[4,3]. It should end up a 0 after the process, as it has 0 equal neighbors.

Comment: @MartinT. Gotcha. This will take a bit of work. Does your data consist of a small number of unique integers? Does it always contain 0? If so, there's just a small tweak you need to do.

Comment: Yes, let's say these are all ( small number of) integers (labels), with a designated one ( say, 0) standing for "null".

Comment: @MartinT. I've updated. Only a small tweak was necessary